# How to put a custom 3D object on a 3D MKMapView in iOS 7.0

Tags: objective-c, opengl, ios7, 3d, apple-maps

I am working on iOS 7.0 app which contains `MKMapView`. I succeeded to make this map 3D using `MKMapCamera`, but I have no idea how to put some **custom** objects, written in COLLADA, to wherever I want on this 3D space.

First question: is it possible to put custom 3D objects on MKMapView?

Second question: if it's possible, what kind of information should I prepare for it? If only 3D polygons (set of 3D vertices) are available, I should look for some different libraries which can convert COLLADA files into some kind of polygon set class.

Comment: MKMapCamera it's not 3D, "These factors let you create a map view that is not just flat but offers a more 3D-like experience." this line from overview of MKMapCamera. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapCamera_class/Reference/Reference.html